# Find intersect between dataframe columns and a second dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

dataframe A

```
    v1  v2  v3
1   wn123   wrr002  tee893
2   ms567   NA  NA
3   NA  sud3003 wrt2229
4   wrs92929    wrw036  syc3647
```

dataframe B

```
ID  TN
1   ms567
2   sud3003
3   syc3647
4   wn123
5   wrr002
6   wrs92929
7   wrt2229
8   wrw036
```

I will like to find overlaps between the 3 columns (per row, that all elements per row in columns v1, v2 and v3) of dataframe A and the entire column of dataframe B$x.

The desired output as a new dataframe C is as follows:

```
v1    v2    
wn123   wrr002
ms567    NA 
sud3003 wrt2229
syc3647 wrw036    syc3647
```

I have tried writing the code this way:

```
getIntersect <- function(x,y){  
return(intersect(x,y))
}

data.frame(apply(A[v1:v3],2, function(x){getIntersect(x,B$TN)}))
```

The code did not work. Any suggestions how to get this code working please?

Comment: I don't get your output. Why are there only two variables in it? You can do what you want with `lapply(df, function(x) intersect(x, df2$TN))`.

Comment: Thanks for that @LAP. I have corrected the output now. I was able to get the correct output without dataframe with this: apply(A[1:3],1,function(x) intersect(x,B$x)) . But I got errors with this: data.frame(apply(A[1:3],1,function(x) intersect(x,B$x)),na.strings = c("", "NA") )  as follows: ...Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1, 3

Comment: I'm not sure that the desired output is correct. `wrs92929` in row 4 of `A` is also in `B`.

Comment: That output still does not make any sense. You have three columns, but only two column names, and the rows 1-3 for column 3 are empty. Wouldn't it be easier to just set elements which are not in dataframe B to `NA` and to keep the structure as it is in dataframe A?

Comment: Thanks @LAP for your help and questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood the question, the OP wants to keep only those entries in `A` which appear in `B`.

This can be solved by rehaping from wide to long format using `melt()`, joining in long format and reshaping back to wide format using `dcast()`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(B)[melt(setDT(A)[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn"), on = .(TN = value), nomatch = 0L][
  , dcast(.SD, rn ~ rowid(rn, prefix = "V"), value.var = "TN")]
```

> ```
>    rn       V1      V2      V3
> 1:  1    wn123  wrr002      NA
> 2:  2    ms567      NA      NA
> 3:  3  sud3003 wrt2229      NA
> 4:  4 wrs92929  wrw036 syc3647
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your code @Uwe. It works as expected. Much appreciated!